# Cannot terminate threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe4

I use threads in my project. And I wanna kill and terminate a thread immediately.

*sample:*

```
    type
      test = class(TThread)
      private
        { Private declarations }
      protected
        procedure Execute; override;
      end;

    var
     Form1: TForm1;
     a:tthread;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure test.Execute;
    begin

      Synchronize(procedure begin    
          form1.ProgressBar1.position := 0;
          sleep(5000);
          form1.ProgressBar1.position := 100;    
      end
      );

    end;

   procedure TForm1.btn_startClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     a:=test.Create(false);
   end;

   procedure TForm1.btn_stopClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     terminatethread(a.ThreadID,1);  //Force Terminate
   end;
```

But when I click on the `btn_stop` (after clicking on `btn_start`), the thread won't stop. **So how can stop this thread immediately?**

BTW `a.terminate;` didn't work too.

Thanks.

Comment: Your main thread is sleeping for 5 seconds, so you can't expect it to do something immediately. Also, there is a difference between `ThreadID` and `Handle`. The `TerminateThread` function expects the thread `Handle`, not `ThreadID`.

Comment: @TLama 1) If I close the application in this 5 seconds, how does windows close this thread? 2)This is a sample. I cannot terminate any threads even without `sleep`... And about your edit: So how can I terminate that? And how can I find a `thread handle`?

Comment: Call it like `TerminateThread(a.Handle, 1);`. You were passing there `ThreadID` which is something different from `Handle`. But note that it's a wrong way to terminate threads.

Comment: @TLama Thank you so much! it just worked ;)

Comment: Best practices says you should look at the Terminated property while in a loop or executing code(in Execute)...and then Terminate...

Comment: *I wanna kill and terminate a
thread immediately.* No, you really don't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a complete misuse of a worker thread. You are delegating all of the thread's work to the main thread, rendering the worker thread useless. You could have used a simple timer instead.

The correct use of a worker thread would look more like this instead:

```
type
  test = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  a: test = nil;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure test.Execute;
var
  I: integer
begin
  Synchronize(
    procedure begin    
      form1.ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
    end
  );

  for I := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    if Terminated then Exit;
    Sleep(1000);
    if Terminated then Exit;
    Synchronize(
      procedure begin
        Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := I * 20;
      end
    );
  end;

  Synchronize(
    procedure begin
      form1.ProgressBar1.Position := 100;    
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  btn_stopClick(nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.btn_startClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if a = nil then
    a := test.Create(False);
end;

procedure TForm1.btn_stopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if a = nil then Exit;
  a.Terminate;
  a.WaitFor;
  FreeAndNil(a);
end;
```

Comment: What Does `a.WaitFor;` do? And can I use `TerminateThread(a.Handle, 1);` instead of `a.Terminate;`? Thanks for the code.

Comment: _You are delegating all of the thread's work to the main thread_  Why? Because of `Synchronize`?

Comment: Yes, because of Synchronize. That's what Synchronize does. It runs the given code in the main thread. If your main thread is running *that* code, then it's obviously not doing anything else at the same time, particularly not handling button-click events.

Comment: No, you cannot use TerminateThread. Read the documentation to learn why not.

Comment: @Sky: `WaitFor()` waits for the thread to terminate. DO NOT use `TerminateThread()` except when you have no other choice (which you do). It is a brute force termination that does not allow the thread to clean up after itself (resources, locks, etc), which can be very dangerous. Always let threads terminate themselves gracefully when possible. That is what the `TThread.Terminate()` method and `TThread.Terminated` property are meant for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the thread waits by using Sleep. This method will keep the thread sleeping for the specified time, no matter what happens around it. In order to be able to "break sleep" you should use an event. The code should be changed to this:

```
procedure test.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(procedure begin    
      form1.ProgressBar1.position := 0;
  end);
  Event.WaitFor(5000);
  if not IsTerminated then
    Synchronize(procedure begin    
        form1.ProgressBar1.position := 100;    
    end);
end;
```

The event should be created and destroyed like this:

```
constructor test.Create(aCreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  Event := TSimpleEvent.Create;
end;

destructor test.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(Event);
  inherited;
end;
```

In order to stop the thread, the code is:

```
procedure TForm1.btn_stopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  a.Terminate;
end;
```

But simply calling Terminate won´t signal the Event, so we have to reimplement Terminate:

```
procedure test.Terminate;
begin
  inherited;
  Event.SetEvent;
end;
```

Calling SetEvent will signal the event, so it will wake the thread up. The execution continues in the next line, that tests for thread termination and decides to execute the second part of the code or not.

Comment: You need a destructor to destroy Event, and you should call inherited first in the constructor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The order of `inherited` in the constructor does not matter. Unlike C++, where ancestor constructors must be called first, Delphi does not have that restriction. The ancestor constructor can be called at the beginning, end, or even the middle of the derived constructor.

Comment: @AlexSC: yes, using a waitable Event is a better sleep choice. I didn't want to confuse Sky with that detail in my answer since he/she is obviously a beginner with thread programming.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: calling inherited before the creation of the event could allow the thread to execute before the TSimpleEvent exits, it depends on what was passed in aCreateSuspended, so I decided to do that way to be sure the object exists when the Execute method runs. Regarding the destructor, I agree and I will edit the post, but that´s something the asker should know, since it´s a basic Delphi practice.

Comment: @Remy I know that of course. The point is that, by convention, we write constructors by calling inherited first. The author here presumably thinks that you have to do it last in a thread because the author thinks the thread will start running as soon as the call to inherited returns. Are you suggesting that it is good practice to call inherited in the middle of your constructor's code? That would be bad advice.

Comment: @Alex You have a basic misunderstanding. The thread is not started until AfterConstruction. So the ordering I suggest works perfectly. In Delphi 5, what you said would have been true, but TThread was changed in Delphi 6.

Comment: @Remy is correct that in this case, the order does not matter. However, when you read the code, say at code review, non-standard ordering will cause raised eyebrows and concern. I was 99% sure that you did it because of a very common misunderstanding about when the OS thread is started. And hence my comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you know that. I know that. Not every one else knows that. Calling an inherited constructor in the middle is possible (in fact, I've seen Borland/Codegear/Embarcadero classes that actually do it), but I wasn't suggesting to actually do it in real practice.