# Background Worker Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, asynchronous, delphi-2006

I would like to prepare asynchronous process for procedure in **Delphi Borland 2006** do you know how?

```
application.ProcessMessages;
  dm001.Proc.Close;
  dm001.Proc.Parameters.Clear;
  dm001.Proc.ProcedureName:='[dbo].[EXAMPLE]';
  dm001.Proc.Parameters.AddParameter.Name:='@idEXAMPLE';
  dm001.Proc.Parameters.ParamByName('@id').DataType:="example";
  dm001.Proc.Parameters.ParamByName('@id').Value:="example";
  dm001.Proc.Open;
```

Example in C#

```cs
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
        }
    }
}
```

or

```cs
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (bw.IsBusy != true)
    {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: `TThread`. It's in the help file. There's a sample in your Delphi Demos folder, in Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\Threads.

Comment: In D2006 you need to use a thread. Create a class derived from `TThread`. If you were using a modern Delphi you could use OTL.

Comment: Another good example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18236774/327083

Comment: Most of my use cases have been to derive from tthread and use one thread to do something in the background with occasional feedbacks, so I wonder why this wasn't made into a component in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BackgroundWorker is not much more than a thread implementation. But there are a Components that emulate this behaviour on Delphi, such as [TBackgroundWorker](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/backgroundworker/)

Comment: Within 30 seconds of examining the source code of this component, I found it calls TerminateThread: a BIG no-no that always leads to undefined behavior.  That ended my investigation as now I don't trust this component to do the right thing without thorough review/revision.  See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811

Answer (score 2):

Tested with TADOQuery for "select" request.

1) Change "ExecuteOptions" "eoAsyncExecute" and "asAsyncFetch" to True

2) Use event "OnFetchProgress" for determinate, does async request was completed. If "Progress" = "MaxProgress" then async request completed.

Tested with Delphi 2007 and 2009.

Answer (score 1):

You may try a well-respected `AsyncCalls` unit. It is not more developed after Delphi 2009 was released, but you don't use it anyway.

- http://www.tommesani.com/index.php/software/altapixshare/21.html
- http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/a/delphi-thread-pool-example-using-asynccalls.htm